# i am getting "parquet-schema: command not found", although i have done cargo install parquet

Tags: rust, parquet

I have installed parquet v2.0.0(**cargo install parquet**) for printing the parquet schema and I am unable to print the schema. I am passing this command
**~/Desktop/new_beginning/abc/abc/hello_cargo$ parquet-schema data/userdata3.parquet true**
parquet-schema: command not found

Comment: Do you have `$HOME/.cargo/bin` in your path?

Comment: nope, I have done now.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have got an answer by doing some search
git clone **https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/rust/parquet**
run these commands in arrow/rust
**cargo run --bin=parquet-schema /home/aditya/Desktop/new_beginning/abc/abc/hello_cargo/data/userdata3.parquet true**
or
**cargo run --bin=parquet-schema /home/aditya/Desktop/new_beginning/abc/abc/hello_cargo/data/userdata3.parquet true 10**
here 10 means,reading will occur upto 10 rows.You can put any valid integer

**cargo run --bin=parquet-read /home/aditya/Desktop/new_beginning/abc/rust_reading_parquet_file/parquet/xyz.parquet**
by default it will read all the lines(rows)